# C# DataGridView and a database flag field

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a field in a database table called "flags" which is a bit field to allow each row to take on several different options. The flags are defined as follows:

```
enum myflags
{
   Delivered = 1,
   Cancelled = 2,
   SpecialOrder = 4
}
```

So the flags field in a row could essentially be Cancelled, Delivered, and specialOrder by having a value of 7.

How can I get these flags working in a DataGridView control within my Windows application. Let's say I wanted to create a DataGridView with a few of the table's fields, and then a checkbox for the cancelled element of the flag - how would I do that?

I cannot use a separate field for each flag meaning - I have to keep it all as one field.

I am using Entity Framework if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the flags as one field in the database but add 3 separate boolean properties to your view model, each reading/writing to the original field. Bind the checkboxes to the newly added boolean properties.